# Why does an intent gets redelivered when returning to activity from recent apps?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

If you launch an activity using Intent with bundled extras, then press home, and the return to that activity from recent apps list.

Then the intent with those bundled extras will be redelivered again.

Anyone knows the reason for this behavior? 
Will it be wise to use Intent.getFlags() and check whether FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY bits 
are turned on, and if yes avoid reading that intent?

Thanks

Comment: Only you can answer this question.  You already know that you can check the flags.  Does your code work OK or not if the Intent is read again?  Actually, what **is** your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyone knows the reason for this behavior?

That's what is supposed to happen. You are also re-delivered any `Bundle` you previously populated with `onSaveInstanceState()`. The objective is for you to present the UI to the user as if you had been around all along.

> Will it be wise to use Intent.getFlags() and check whether FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY bits are turned on, and if yes avoid reading that intent?

Generally speaking, I would think that it would be wise to read the `Intent` and do whatever it calls for. Bear in mind that your activity may be newly created, if Android had terminated your process in between your app moving to the background and the user returning to your app from the recent-tasks list.

If there is state information that you need, to determine whether or not you already did some work of relevance to this operation, store that in the `onSaveInstanceState()` `Bundle`, or perhaps derive it from a persistent store.

That being said, you are certainly welcome to look for that flag and do something different in that case, if it is truly needed. Just make sure that you think it through and make sure that this is really what's correct for your circumstance.

Comment: I see, I just encountered the issue when I was handling intents coming from a the Facebook app launching my app, and seeing those intents redelivered again when coming from recents due to recreation of the activity seemed odd, so it's my responsibility then to decide how to behave. Thanks

Comment: @MaxRaskin: "so it's my responsibility then to decide how to behave" -- yes. I think that [idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) is a useful design goal for an activity, so that it can be launched once, twice, or more times without causing harm. However, some operations will not work that way (e.g., an activity honoring `ACTION_INSERT` should note whether it actually has already modified the data store, so that if it is launched again, it does not insert again).